# What does Zach mean by "Machu Picchu"?

Tags: dialogue, life-after-beth

At the end of the movie Life After Beth (2014), Zach mentioned "Machu Picchu", but I did not understand the meaning. What did he say and why?

Comment: I at least assume you know what [Machu Picchu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machu_Picchu) is?

Comment: Yes, but did he literally meant Machu Picchu or was he referring to something else?

Comment: Can you include the full quote?

Comment: No, I can't remember the full quote, I just recall him saying that, maybe he meant literally the place...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, he meant the actual place.** Zach wanted to get somewhere far away and this is the most remote place he could think of. It's also an amusing line because he's being desperate and naive:

> I think we need to get far away from here where the zombies can't get to us. [...] Machu Picchu. It's remote and safe. Look, I've got a map. I think if we take side streets and sidewalks...

He probably got the idea earlier in the film: when he finds out that Beth is alive, they watch TV together with her parents and **the show is about Machu Picchu.**